# table view cells with different controls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I was working with the grouped table view , and i wanted different controls for every row i.e switch control for 1st,radio button for 2nd ,checkbox for 3rd and so on.. how can this be implemented programmatically that is without using interface builder

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CharlieMezak said is right, you need to create in UIControls directly in cellForRowAtIndexPath , and add as subviews to contentView of the cell

For reference see the link below
http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder

the link specifies the code to create cells programmatically as well as using IB.

Comment: hey how to get the different controls  on each row . like buttons on 1st , switch on second.We usually get the same controls on every row.

Comment: @sameer: basing on indexPath.row value u need to create each control whatever u have to show..

Answer (score 1):

[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)

Read the programing guide, and remember to use different CellIdentifier for each type of cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty vague question.

Obviously you need to provide the cells to the tableview in its `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate/datasource method. So, either in that method or during the initialization of your view controller, build the UITableViewCell instances that you need, adding the various controls that you want to them as subviews and connecting the controls to your view controller so you can detect when they have been changed. Then just return the appropriate cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Personally, I think it's a lot easier to use IB in cases like this. Just create an IBOutlet instance variable for each custom cell you want, and return the right cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.